# How can I pass an object in addition to json from my ajax function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
function submitHandler(dialog) {

    dialog.$submits.disableBt();
    dialog.$message.addMessage("loading", "<li>Contacting Server, please wait ...</li>");
    $.ajax({
        url: href,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: dialog.$form.serializeArray()
    })
        .done(onSubmitDone())
        .fail(onSubmitFail());
}
```

This function has a parameter of dialog which is an object looking like this:

```
{
        $modal: $modal,
        $form: $modal.find('.form'),
        $message: $modal.find('.message'),
        $submits: $modal.find('.submit-button'),
        href: $form.attr('data-href')
    };
```

I need to send the dialog object to the onSubmitDone and onSubmitFail functions. Previously I was not using an object
to hold $modal, $form etc and the variables were all available to all functions that were enclosed within an outer function

Two questions:

**Is it sensible to pass things around as parts of an object or should I just declare these variables at the top of an outer function.**

If I do pass around the object how can I pass it to the following:

```
function onSubmitDone(json) {
    json = json || {};
    if (json.Success) {
        switch (action) {
```

I understand that my json object is passed but how can I pass the dialog object also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass your object as the `context` option of `$.ajax`, it will be available as `this` inside `onSubmitDone` and `onSubmitFail`:

```
var jsonObj; // do you really need this global?

function submitHandler(dialog) {
    jsonObj=dialog.$form.serializeArray();
    dialog.$submits.disableBt();
    dialog.$message.addMessage("loading", "<li>Contacting Server, please wait ...</li>");
    $.ajax({
        url: href,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: jsonObj ,
        context: dialog
    })
        // Don't call the handlers from here, no ()!
        .done(onSubmitDone)
        .fail(onSubmitFail);
}

// Receives the data from the server
function onSubmitDone(response) {
    // your object is available as 'this':
    console.log(this.$modal);
}

// Different params here, but 'this' is the same
function onSubmitFail(jqXHR, textStatus) { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of passing your dialog argument to the ajax callbacks is to enclose it in the callbacks definition, as showed bellow:

```
function submitHandler(dialog) {
    dialog.$submits.disableBt();
    dialog.$message.addMessage("loading", "<li>Contacting Server, please wait ...</li>");
    $.ajax({
        url: href,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: dialog.$form.serializeArray(),
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            onSubmitDone(data, textStatus, jqXHR, dialog);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            onSubmitFail(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown, dialog);
        }
    });
}
```

I made explicit all callback arguments (data, textStatus, jqXHR, errorThrown), but you don't need to use all of them if you don't want to.

Comment: my data is json so could I just use onSubmitDone(json, dialog). I have all these functions inside an outer function that's declared at the start of my file. What do you think about my just using a few common global (to the outer function) variables and not passing all this stuff from place to place?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this **done** approach, but I guess it would work if you called it like **done(function () { onSubmitDone(json, dialog); });**. Regarding variables usage it is up to your needs, if you are not using some of them it makes no sense to pass them arround as you have pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

[Underscore js](http://underscorejs.org/) is a unique and really awesome library for object handling and manipulation

Since you want to pass your object is wise to declare it outside of the functions
Then you can access your object's parts and work with them in your functions' body.

Your code will look like this:

```
var jsonObj;    
function submitHandler(dialog) {
        jsonObj=dialog.$form.serializeArray();
        dialog.$submits.disableBt();
        dialog.$message.addMessage("loading", "<li>Contacting Server, please wait ...</li>");
        $.ajax({
            url: href,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data:jsonObj 
        })
            .done(onSubmitDone(jsonObj))
            .fail(onSubmitFail(jsonObj));
    }
```

Comment: But how can I access the json data returned from my ajax call in the onSubmitDone function?

Comment: Oh, I just misunderstood the question, let me improve it

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question if it is sensible to pass the object around, while you can, you might find it gets a little burdensome to do so, needing to lug the variable around whenever you need to use it. I would recommended encapsulating your dialog object in the parent scope of your submitHandler() function so it is available to submitHandler, onSubmitDone, etc.

Regarding your second question if you were to pass it around and how you'd get the dialog object to your onSubmitDone function as well, you can always pass the response and your dialog object to your onSubmitDone function like so:

```
.done(onSubmitDone(response, dialog))
```

Comment: What would you say to the idea of me just not using a dialog object and storing those variables in the parent scope?  It seems I might be making things more complicated than needed as all of these functions are defined inside another encapsulating function inside the one file.